# Pick colors from Image - Android

Tags: android, image, colors, picker

i'm new to image color picking on Java, or to be specific, on Android. All I understand is that I have to create a custom view for an image, I dunno about the rest.

Are there any specific examples that shows how to show color codes and color from an image?

Answer (score -1):

You can check this source code out :

http://www.tneoh.zoneit.com/java/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.java

Comment: Not Found

The requested URL /java/ColorPicker/ColorPicker.java was not found on this server.